# How to share the x axis in reverse between two subplots in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to show two different anatomical views of a subject, front and back, and I want the coordinates to be consistent between both while also showing them as you would naturally see them. This means that the X axis should increase to the right in the front view and to the left in the back view.

I want the navigation actions (pan, zoom) to affect both views at the same time. For example, if I zoom on the left shoulder of the subject in the front view (which would be located on the right side of the image) I want the back view to also zoom on the left shoulder (which would be located on the left side of the image).

Usually this is achieved by sharing the axis with something like the `sharex` and `sharey` parameters. However, as I said, I want the X axis (and only the X axis) in the second subplot to be reversed, and that option forces the limits on both subplots to go the same way.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it does not look like there is a specific functionality already implemented for what I'm trying to achieve, so after a bit of tinkering this is the simplest that I was able to come up with.

I am integrating this into a Qt application and I had already modified the navigation toolbar to hide some actions and change some shortcuts. What I have ended up doing is overriding the following methods from my custom navigation toolbar class:

```py
class CustomNavigationToolbar(NavigationToolbar):
    ...

    def release_zoom(self, event) -> None:
        zoom_axes = self._zoom_info.axes[0]
        other_axes = [a for a in self.canvas.figure.get_axes() if a != zoom_axes][0]
        super().release_zoom(event)
        other_axes.set_ylim(zoom_axes.get_ylim())
        other_axes.set_xlim(reversed(zoom_axes.get_xlim()))
        self.canvas.draw_idle()

    def drag_pan(self, event) -> None:
        pan_axes = self._pan_info.axes[0]
        other_axes = [a for a in self.canvas.figure.get_axes() if a != pan_axes][0]
        super().drag_pan(event)
        other_axes.set_ylim(pan_axes.get_ylim())
        other_axes.set_xlim(reversed(pan_axes.get_xlim()))
        self.canvas.draw_idle()
```

For the zoom action the view is updated when the mouse button is release (the `release_zoom` method) so I get the other axes first and, after the call to `super()`, I update the X and Y limits based on the zoomed axes. Same thing for the pan action, but this is updated while the mouse is being dragged (the `drag_pan` method).

Please note, this works for my use case because I'm guaranteed to only have two axes, but it wouldn't be difficult to adapt to more than two.